# Is IONIC 4 beta stable?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I will start a project at the beginning of 2019 (January or February). Maybe a bit later.

Will it be better to start with **the current version (3.9)** , or should I start **with version 4 which is currently on Beta** but may be released soon. depending on the Ionic team life-cycle development. Any advise ideas are welcome

Any info about their roadmap?

**I know it's not the best location to ask ... But I think that some people are wondering the same question!**
revision 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The right place to ask this would be in **[Ionic's forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/)**, not here.

Comment: @sebaferreras I know you right I post there and also on GitHub Ionic project to get different opinions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently working with multiple Ionic 4 projects, I would have to say that the documentation is not the best for this version. There are still bugs here and there and some package issues (e.g. ionic-native packages) but seems to be in the right direction. It is a personal decision which one to use based on your project. 
I personally prefer to go with Ionic 4 since the angular adaptation makes it easier for me to work around.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not. I recently upgraded my project from 3.19 to 4 and I regret doing so. I knew I might have this problem. I proceeded anyway as my cli would not desist from troubling to ugrade to the latest version.

First, I had problem with platforms, especially android platform. Later, I could not build. Then it started giving me all sorts of incomprehensible gradle errors.

I did all I could, I removed plaforms folder, added again, removed node_modules, run `npm install` again. Nope nothing worked.

Now I am going back to my earlier version.

So in my opinion, don't use it for production.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the beta version and also updated one of my projects from version 3 to version 4 and got a lot of errors. I think we have to wait for the actual release.